# lstinline gobbles space with linebreak

Tags: listings, inline

When I compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[R/3 6.10]ABAP,
    breaklines=true,}

\begin{document}
\lstinline|METHODS print_number IMPORTING VALUE(iv_number) TYPE i.|
\end{document}
```

The space between `(iv_number)` and `TYPE` is gobbled. It is not even there when copy & pasting. This seems to be related to the breaklines option. For my actual document I would need that option. Is there some global method to solve the problem? I would prefer that to writing `\lstinline[breaklines=f]|METHODS print_number IMPORTING VALUE(iv_number) TYPE i.|` everytime.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you can use [`minted`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) instead of `listings`. I used `listings` before and had to manually set a lot of things that `minted` does out of the box.

Comment: This is nice! It took a bit of work to switch and customize again but minted seems to be the superior solution!

Comment: I believe that not solving your `listings` problem may have been the better solution ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `minted` avoids these problems. The package is a bit more work to [install](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) but it is much more flexible.

The example with minted would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[ABAP]{breaklines=true}

\begin{document}
\mintinline{ABAP}{METHODS print_number IMPORTING VALUE(iv_number) TYPE i.}
\end{document}
```

You can even set options just for inline code with:

```
\setmintedinline[ABAP]{breaklines=false}
```